# how to use export method in jsplumb?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I using this code, but it not working.
please help me.

```
var toolkit = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance();
var data = toolkit.export();
console.log(data);
```

I get this javascript error : 
Uncaught TypeError: t.export is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

I find out answer for my question:

according to jsPlumb documentation, for get current nodes, edges and ports data, using export() method but this doesn't work. I using exportData() method and I get  nodes, edges and ports data correctly.